# How does the Stosszahlansatz work in quantum mechanics?

Tags: thermodynamics, density-operator

Is there a formulation emergence of the Stosszahlansatz in quantum mechanics with density matrices?

> Stosszahlansatz is the assumption that the velocities of colliding
> particles are uncorrelated, and independent of position. This means
> the probability that a pair of particles with given velocities will
> collide can be calculated by considering each particle separately and
> ignoring any correlation between the probability for finding one
> particle with velocity $v$ and probability for finding another
> velocity $v$ in a small region $\delta r$.

I don't know a quantum resolution of this [problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/391382/150174).

> Boltzmann why he could assign a sign to his H-theorem, i.e., how could
> he force time to go in one direction? Boltzmann apparently quipped a
> remark along the lines of "Show me an example where it does the
> opposite."

Like I have heard of buzzwords like "quantum BBGKY hierarchy" but I am unaware of they fix this problem. An exposition of this would be insightful?